# The chachamim on peace

Tags: sources-mekorot, parshanut-torah-comment, commentaries, shalom-peace

Our *chachamim* teach that when there is peace and harmony between a man and his wife, the Divine Presence dwells with them.

Does anyone know where the *chachamim* says this?

Comment: Your question was really two questions; I edited it to keep the one that matches the title. You can [edit] further; and [ask the other question as a separate question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Please do not edit your question in such a way that it invalidates existing upvoted answers.

Comment: @Chiddushei Torah, feel free to ask your other question in a [new question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Two tangentially related questions in one don't work on this site.

Comment: How do you know our chachamim teach that?

Answer (score 9):

[Sotah 17a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=18&daf=17&format=pdf):

> דריש ר''ע איש ואשה זכו שכינה ביניהן לא זכו אש אוכלתן
>
> R. Akiba expounded: When husband and wife are worthy, the Shechinah abides with them; when they are not worthy fire consumes them.

(*Soncino translation*)

Rashi [there](http://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Sotah.17a.23?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) explains:

> **שכינה ביניהם** - שהרי חלק את שמו ושיכנו ביניהן יו"ד באיש וה"י באשה
>
> **The Shechinah abides with them** - God split His Name, and put it between them; "איש" has the letter יו"ד , and "אשה" has the letter
> ה"י, which form Hashem's name.
>
> **לא זכו אש אוכלתן** - שהקב"ה מסלק שמו מביניהן ונמצאו אש ואש
>
> **If they are not worthy fire consumes them** - Because God removes (the letters of) his Name from them, and you're left with אש and אש
> (fire and fire).

(*my translation*)